# Default Excel keyboard shortcut CTRL + ALT + F5 no longer works

Tags: excel, excel-2007

The *Microsoft Excel* keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to Refresh All was one of my favorites until it stopped working.  Presently, when I enter that key combination nothing (as far as I can see) happens.  I've had to live without it for so long that I can't recall if there was anything specific that was changed prior to it no longer working. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> continues to work to Refresh a specific PivotTable, but that has limited value.

The version is *Excel 2007*.

How can I discover what is preventing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> from working and restore its default functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this problem by disabling *Intel Graphics* hotkeys:

Right-click on the desktop, hover over the menu option "Graphics Options" > "Hot Keys" > click Disable.

I had the exact same issue described above, albeit on Excel 2013 then eventually worked out that the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (as well as other <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> keys) is reserved by the Intel Graphics control panel. I'd never even noticed this program but it's accessible by right-clicking on the desktop and selecting 'Graphics Properties...'. The Intel Graphics control panel doesn't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> by default, but it still reserves it apparently. I can assure you that disabling the Intel Graphics hot keys allows me to be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in Excel straight away.

Hope that helps!

By the way, this same solution is shown here for a different user problem:
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/W-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/hotkeys-Alt-Ctrl-F1-Alt-Ctrl-F5-which-pre-install-application/td-p/1318777

Comment: You saved my life! I love you! :D

Comment: Thank you very much. My system configuration was Windows 10 Anniversary Edition+Microsoft Office 365 2016 Pro Plus Excel + Lenovo W540.

Comment: This fixed it.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

[Keyposé](http://jungsbluth.de/magnus/blog/2008/08/01/keypose-flavour-your-screencasts-with-shortcuts/) is a free download which displays keyboard shortcuts as you use them. This makes sure that your hardware and OS are working as expected. If you see your shortcut appear with this tool (or you can verify <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> work in other applications another way) then the change must be within Excel itself

You might have more luck posting this on superuser.com

Comment: I'll have to look into that.  Since you mentioned SuperUser, do you think perhaps this question is in the wrong forum?  I didn't intend to misdirect the question - I saw several similar questions about Excel in StackOverflow and thought it would be the right place.